# How to display a Google map with Knockout js and html

Tags: javascript, java, html, knockout.js

I am new to js and know very little about Knockout. I have tried some tutorials but it still makes no sense. Anyway, I want to know how I would get the same results as the HTML below using Knockout.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
 #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 800px;
     }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Map</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-3.3.0.js'></script>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            center: {lat: 39.962386, lng: -82.999563},
            zoom: 14
        });
        var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: 39.969819, lng: -83.01012},
          animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
          map: map,
          title: 'EXPRESS LIVE!'
        });
          var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: 39.969424, lng: -83.005915},
          animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
          map: map,
          title: 'Nationwide Arena'
        });
          var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: 39.964425, lng: -82.987804},
          animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
          map: map,
          title: 'Columbus Museum of Art' 
        });
          var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: 39.959688, lng: -83.007202},
          animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
          map: map,
          title: 'COSI' 
        });
          var marker5 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: 39.969161, lng: -82.987289},
          animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
          map: map,
          title: 'Columbus State College' 
        });
          var marker6 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: 39.946266, lng: -82.991023},
          animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
          map: map,
          title: "Schmidt's Sausage Haus und Restaurant" 
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAzDEepTI6qMIoZ3OGMe03ZWpmrIakZCwc&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have looked at multiple posts on this site on the topic but I cannot get any of the answers to work for me.

Comment: what exactly is the question? The code snippet shows your map...

Comment: i want to do that using knockout js in a separate js file instead of the in the html file. i have yet to fine a solution that works for me.

Comment: What is the logic of what you are trying to achieve here? Are the markers going to change position? Do they need to be Knockout observables? Do you need to reuse this map in multiple pages? If you explain the final result you want, we could help more!

Comment: alright i just didn't want others to do too much of the work for me so i was keeping the scope small. i am going to use knock out to create a search bar to filter the icons and turn them on/off when a search is entered. as well as giving the markers info windows  filled with info from the wiki api on that location.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a binding handler that did all the referencing to the external library and template manipulation.

```
/**
 * Decorates a div with a map and adds marker points
 */

ko.bindingHandlers.googleMap = {

    init(mapDiv, valueAccessor) {
        let bindingData = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()) || {},
        map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
           center: {
               lat: bindingData.centerX, 
               lng: bindingData.centerY
           },
           zoom: bindingData.zoom
        }),
        markers = _.map(bindingData.markers,function (data) {
           return new google.maps.Marker(data);
        });

        // do some more stuff or hook into markers
        // you might want to subscribe to the markers collection 
        // if you make it an observable array
     }

   };
```

Referencing it in the template would be something like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='map-div' data-bind="googleMap:googleMapData"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in the viewModel specify something like:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
   this.googleMapData = ko.observable({
      centerX: 39.962386,
      centerY: -82.999563,
      zoom: 14,
      markers: [{
         position: {lat: 39.964425, lng: -82.987804},
         animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
         map: map,
         title: 'Columbus Museum of Art' 
      },
        ...
      ]
   });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

[Added a Fiddle to help](https://jsfiddle.net/4ogrp7s2/2/) - just replace your API key in the maps API library included.

Comment: alright but what about the map key do i leave it as is or will it need to be changed to fit the new set up      <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAzDEepTI6qMIoZ3OGMe03ZWpmrIakZCwc&callback=initMap">
    </script>

Comment: also i was hoping to learn a little bit more about the relation between the knockout file and the html. as it stands i can not seem to get your implementation to run and my console gives no errors. i am not sure if i have properly linked my html and js files.

Comment: Yeah -- I am sorry - I suppose I assumed you had a little more experience with knockout.  

the ko.applyBindings with the viewModel object being passed in takes any own properties in the template and binds them to properties in the viewModel.  
You would need to include ko library and the binding handler call first.  That will put KO into the window scope and attach the binding handler to KO.  Then the viewModel comes after.  I will make a fiddle that better illustrates this.